# Redact content in Word document

Tags: security, ms-word

I need a way of "redacting" content in a word document.
At first I tried changing the range's background color to match the foreground color, and it looks great.

...but the text is still there. And can be copy/pasted, and the background color can still be changed back so the text is readable again.
Especially if the document is saved as a PDF this is easy. Just copy/paste the text into notepad, and everything is readable.

So not very secure :-(

So I need a way of changing the content to something else, so i can't just be changed back. Maybe shapes or other characters, like x'es. But this change must not move anything else in the document - it has to take up the same amount of space.

It doesn't HAVE to be entire black bars like in the screenshots below, blacking each word would be okay too if that's easier, leaving the spaces between words visible.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

It would be nice to be able to redact pictures in the document aswell, but for now text is my main focus.
I suspect images would be easier, since they can most likely just be replaced by black shapes.

Comment: Word is not the best choice for this as it's not possible to be absolutely certain where a graphic is going to be positioned AND whether it will stay there. If security is a major question, then this is definitely a factor.

Comment: I'm quite aware that it's not ideal, but it's still a problem I need to solve as good as possible. As mentioned it shouldn't move anything around in the document. This is because when redacting content, it's generally because you need to release a copy of a document containing classified information, without the classified information being disclosed. - So the rest of the document content won't be change, and thus content shouldn't move around. It's supposed to be a static (but censored) copy.

Comment: I guessed as much (TV, movies)...

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the following pointers, but "your mileage may vary".

1. Make sure you can see the object anchors (File/Options/Display). When an image is selected, an anchor symbol should appear next to the character in the text the "floating" object is associated with. This is of the utmost importance for you.
2. Insert and position a black box.
3. Display the advanced Layout options (right-click and choose "More Layout options" for example in Word 2010).
4. Make sure "Move with text" is checked - VERY IMPORTANT
5. Set the "Absolute position" horizontally to "to the right of CHARACTER".
6. Set the "Absolute position" vertically to "below line".
7. "OK" to close the dialog box
8. DRAG the anchor symbol to the left-most character the box should "stick to".
9. Check the "Lock anchor" option - VERY IMPORTANT

Now, the black box should move exactly with the anchoring text.

EDIT: Removing the text makes things a bit more complicated, but if you use a Range object in the code it shouldn't be a problem

10. Choose the text wrapping "INLINE"
11. You should then be able to delete the text

To get started on the necessary code for the positioning options outlined above (5-8) would be to record a macro to get the syntax. The key to positioning relative to CHARACTER and LINE is to set the `Anchor` correctly, which is a parameter of the `Shapes.AddTextbox` method to the target `Range`.

The trickiest part, I believe, is going to be getting the necessary height and width of the bars... The Range.Information(wdRelativeHorizontalPosition) is probably what we need for the latter. If the text has an "exact" line height that will help for the former.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I understand your answer correctly, you suggest placing a black shape on top of the text to be redacted. If so, it won't work, since the text will still be there, although not visible - it could still be copy/pasted out of the document. That's why I need the redacted text removed entirely, though without moving the rest of the document content. Also, this is indeed thought to be a programming question, since I wish to do this via a macro. I just couldn't post any code, since I don't know where to begin, hence this question :-)

Comment: OK, I've taken that into account with the manual steps. It works for me in a quick test, manually. Getting it in code will probably involve quite a bit of testing and "tweaking"...